I wrote a function for an online store, but for some reason the part of the function where the product is added to the cart stopped working
I wrote a function for an online store, but for some reason the part of the function where the product is added to the cart stopped working. I'm just a beginner and I can't find a solution myself yet. help me what is the problem
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { FaShoppingCart } from "react-icons/fa";
import Order from './Order';

const showOrders = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Ваш заказ:</h2>
      {props.orders.map(el => (
      <Order key={el.id} item={el}/>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

const showNothing = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Ваша корзина пуста.</h2>
    </div>
  )
}


export default function Header(props) {
  let [cartOpen, setCartOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <header>
        <div>
      <span className='logo'>House Staff</span> 
      <ul className='nav'>
        <li>Про нас</li> 
        <li>Контакты</li>  
        <li>Кабинет</li>       
      </ul>
      <FaShoppingCart onClick={() => setCartOpen(cartOpen = !cartOpen)} className={`shop-cart-button ${cartOpen && 'active'}`}/>

        {cartOpen && (
          <div className='shop-cart'>
            {props.orders.lenght > 0 ?
            showOrders(props) : showNothing()}
          </div>
        )}
          

      </div>
      <div className='presentation'></div>
    </header>
  )
}


Welcome to StackOverflow! As you don't show the code, that adds a product to the card, we can't check it. But maybe the content of your cart is just not shown because of the misspelling of props.orders.lenght. Try changing it to props.orders.length.
